# add param value to all the object

Tags: javascript, parameters

hello i want to add param value to all the object in a page. like

param name="wmode" value="transparent"

to all the object. how can i do that

Comment: What do you mean by "object"? Are you referring to input fields.

Comment: @levik: I think he means <object> tags

Comment: thanks derobert, yes i do mean object tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like you are trying to manipulate some embedded SWFs? .. maybe take a look at [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) as it takes care of a lot of this for you